# Python: Replace certain words in string with another word? Without built in functions?

Tags: python

Anyone know how to do this?

Ex:

Replace sstring with sreplace in string s

s = "111sstring111"

expected output: "111sreplace111"

Comment: Why can't you use `str.replace`?

Comment: Whiteboard/interview

Comment: Surely the instructor who assigned you this task, a) gave a lecture or b) assigned some reading/videos or c) assigned a text book or d) all of the above. Are there NO in-course resource for you to use to get started on this task. Then, if you have code that fails in some way, come back with a specific, well-researched question.

Comment: Not sure if that's what your interviewer wanted: `s[0:4] + 'replace' + s[-3:]`

Comment: im sure they wouldnt want this in production code ... its probably to test his grasp of algorithms (and of coarse they understand interviews can be lots of pressure)  ... I posted an answer but again its probably not what the interviewer wanted

Comment: I dont disagree ... but its really probably not that bad of an interview question depending on what skills you wanted to test :P ...  of coarse A+ if the question had a time limit that allowed having the internet do it for you, and thats what they were testing... but i somehow doubt it, this is likely intrepid finding out how he can improve for next time ...

Comment: The most likely scenario here is that such an interview question is actually aimed at finding out how comfortable the applicant is with abandoning good, simple code in favor of harebrained ideas.

Answer (score 3):

```
replacement.join(s.split(target))
```

i guess ... but its probably not going to help the interviewr with your grasp of algorithms ... it would only reveal your grasp of python

```
re.sub(target,replacement,s) #would also work
```

if you are looking for an algorithm that uses no builtins you should probably say that in the question

Comment: why -1? just curious?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option, but again it mostly just tests your python knowledge.

```
index = theString.find(sstring)
if index != -1:
    theString = theString[:index] + sreplace + theString[index + len(sstring):]
```

Same idea, generalized for more than one occurrence:

```
newString = ""
index = theString.find(search)
while index != -1:
    newString = newString + theString[:index] + rep 
    theString = theString[index + len(sstring):]
    index = theString.find(search)
newString += theString
```

Comment: good answer(+1) , but its worth noting this only replaces the first occurance (ie it would work for the given example...)

Comment: if its for an interview, then I don't think this is what he/she is looking for

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option using `re.sub`, which is basically a more flexible `str.replace`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "111sstring111"
>>> re.sub('sstring', 'sreplace', s)
'111sreplace111'
```